# Change name of files in a directory: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I have .wav files in the directory "dataset"

```
import os
dataset_path = 'C:/dataset'

def change_filenames(dataset_path):

    i = 0  # target filename
    for old_name in os.listdir(dataset_path):
        os.rename(old_name, str(i) + '.wav')
        i+=1    

change_filenames(dataset_path)
```

Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'sound1.wav' -> '0.wav'

What is the error mean? The file is in the directory and is reachable by the code, why not system?

Comment: Did you try with absolute path ?

Comment: Adding on to @Bipul's point, also consider your current working directory (when in doubt always use the full path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zerodf points out, the problem is likely that your current working directory is not the same as the `dataset_path` directory you specified. So when `os.rename` goes to rename `sound1.wav`, it looks for it in your current working directory (which might not be the same as `dataset_path`), can't find it, and throws that error.

Since your `dataset_path` variable contains an absolute path, you can make sure that everything that `os.rename` tries to rename is an absolute path by tacking each filename onto `dataset_path` using os.path.join(). That is, change

```
os.rename(old_name, str(i) + '.wav')
```

to

```
os.rename(os.path.join(dataset_path, old_name), os.path.join(dataset_path, str(i) + '.wav'))
```

Then when `os.rename` goes to rename `sound1.wav`, it will look for `C:/dataset/sound1.wav`, which it should find without a problem.

Also note that you can see what your current working directory is with the `getcwd()` function in `os`.

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: It's safer to use `os.path.join(...)` instead of string concatenation for file paths.

Comment: @noslenkwah Aha, thank you. I was trying to remember what that command was. Updating answer. To those who don't know, os.path.join() uses the system's default directory delimiter ("/" or "\\", etc.) to join two parts of a file path together.